# Java Spanish Encoding in Properties File

Tags: java, character-encoding, properties-file

So I'm working on a localization example and the normal method of doing it with `ResourceBundle` and everything doesn't support UTF-8 it seems so I'm moving on to `Properties`.

I've got it getting the actual properties fine but in the Spanish file, it doesn't like the accents. I have it reading in UTF-8 but it doesn't care, just displays a different symbol than before.

**Output:**

```
íHola!
┐C¾mo estßs?
íAdi¾s!
```

**Expected Output:**

```
¡Hola!
¿Cómo estás?
¡Adios!
```

**Properties File:**

```
greetings = ¡Hola!
farewell = ¡Adiós!
inquiry = ¿Cómo estás?
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String language;
        String country;

        if (args.length != 2) {
            language = new String("en");
            country = new String("GB");
        } else {
            language = new String(args[0]);
            country = new String(args[1]);
        }

        String file = String.format("lang_%s_%s.properties",language,country);

        InputStream utf8in = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(utf8in, "UTF-8");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(reader);

        System.out.println(props.getProperty("greetings"));
        System.out.println(props.getProperty("inquiry"));
        System.out.println(props.getProperty("farewell"));
    }

}
```

I've just spent about 40 minutes reading everything I could find and  they were either the exact same as what I've got now or slightly different and when trying, produced the same results.

Can someone please tell me how I can get my expected output?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. It works fine in Eclipse with an UTF-8 Console setting. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to change the Windows Console to UTF-8. Interestingly "System.console().writer().println(props.getProperty("greetings"));" works fine on a Windows Console. Maybe that helps

Comment: I tried it in Eclipse with the UTF-8 Console setting and it displayed small blacked out diamonds instead of the characters. Command Prompt can be changed running a command but it's iffy and doesn't always work. Plus it requires that you change the font. I'm going to have to look at that snippet.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, I can be reproduced the problem. Here are steps:

1. Create Java project and set **Text file encoding** to `CP850`.
2. Create **Run/Debug Configurations**, set **VM arguments** to `-Dfile.encoding=ISO8859-1`.
   Confirm **Encoding** setting in Common tab is `CP850`;
3. Run the java program.

When java program print to standard output, those chars become `ISO8859-1` bytes.
Those bytes are re-encoded using `CP850` and display in Console view.

This is a configuration problem. Make sure the **Encoding** is the same as the `file.encoding` of running program.